# how to validate only accept first letter as a character & remaining as a numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I want to validate textbox that only first as a character & remaining the numbers & should not accept special characters.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSlip" runat="server" CssClass="smalltextbox" PlaceHolder="Slip" Width="80px" OnKeypress="javascript:return FirstChar(event,this.value);" MaxLength="6" />

//First Letter Only Charactor Remaining Numbers
function FirstChar(event) {
var firstChar = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
if (firstChar <= '9' && firstChar >= '0') {
    //do your stuff
    return true;
}
return true;
}
```

For Example : "A00001" like this..
But it does not work for me.. Anyone help, thanks in advance..

Comment: the name of a function doesn't limit when it's run

Comment: give one example here what do you mean by special characters ?

Comment: i need the result like "A00001" when enter text in text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer with the help of Sathiya saravana Babu answer

```
 function FirstChar(event, val) {
var length = val.length;
var firstChar = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
if (length != 0) {
    var firstChar = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (firstChar >= '48' && firstChar <= '57') {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
} else {

if (length == 0) {
    var firstChar = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if ((firstChar >= '65' && firstChar <= '90') || (firstChar >= '97' && firstChar <= '122')) {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
}
```

thank you all, its works fine..

Answer (score 1):

```
function FirstChar(event,val) {
var length=val.length;
 var firstChar = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
if(length!=0)
{

       // console.log(firstChar);
        if (firstChar >= '48' && firstChar <= '57') {

            return true;
        }else
        {
        return false;
        }
}else
{

        if (firstChar >= '48' && firstChar <= '57') {

            return false;
        }else
        {


        return true;
        }

}
}
```

Comment: hi sathiya thanks for your answer,  it works almost close to my expected answer, but its also accepts number as a first character.. can u help..

Comment: i have edit the code. try it and let me know if any issues

Answer (score 1):

```
 function FirstChar(event, val) {
     var length = val.length;

     if (length != 0) {
         var firstChar = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
         console.log(firstChar);

         if (length != 1) {

             if (firstChar >= '48' && firstChar <= '57') 
             {
                 return true;
             } else 
             {
                 return false;
             }
         } 
       else 
       {
             if (firstChar <= '48' && firstChar >= '57')
             {
                 return true;
             } else 
             {
                 return false;
             }
         }
     } 
     else 
     {
         return true;
     }
 }
```

Please check this modified version Sathiya saravana Babu answer.